# Create a list of all available assets by checking previous entries in table

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-entities, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a series of models that I use to track assets in our database. However, the primary two involved with this procedure are `Computer` and `ComputerTracking`. `ComputerTracking` holds a list of all actions taken with each specific computer inside a field called `AssetActionsId`. `AssetActionId` refers to another model that simply holds the actions.

Currently there are only three actions:

```
-----------------------
|ID    AssetActionName|
-----------------------
|1     Check In       |
|2     Check Out      |
|3     Decommission   |
-----------------------
```

I need a method of displaying all computers that are available from `Computer`. As in, they have either a status of `Check In` or haven't ever been checked out or decommissioned.

My model for `ComputerTracking` is:

```
public partial class ComputerTracking
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Computer")]
    public int ComputerId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Employee")]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Condition")]
    public int ConditionId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Condition Notes")]
    public string ConditionNotes { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Date Entered")]
    public DateTime? EnteredDate { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Action")]
    public int AssetActionId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Last Modified")]
    public DateTime? LastModified { get; set; }

    public virtual AssetAction AssetAction { get; set; }
    public virtual Computer Computer { get; set; }
    public virtual Condition Condition { get; set; }
}
```

My controller generates a list of all computers using the following method:

```
ViewBag.ComputerIdentifier = db.Computers.ToList().Select(t => new GroupedSelectListItem
{
    GroupKey = t.ComputerModel.Manufacturer.Id.ToString(),
    GroupName = t.ComputerModel.Manufacturer.ManufacturerName,
    Text = t.ComputerIdentifier,
    Value = t.Id.ToString()
});
```

**EDIT:**

Here is an SQL query that does precisely what I want:

```
USE shop_db
SELECT  t1.id
        ,t1.ComputerModelId
        ,t1.SerialNumber
FROM    asset.Computer t1
LEFT JOIN asset.ComputerTracking t2 
        ON t1.id = t2.ComputerId
WHERE   t1.id NOT IN(SELECT ComputerId FROM asset.ComputerTracking)
        OR t2.AssetActionId=1
```

Comment: Do you have any code for what you have tried so far?

Comment: Frankly, I'm not entirely sure where to start. The project is rather large, but what I posted above is essentially what I have. I currently just list every computer, and it's up to the person entering to know what is on hand or not.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using linq to entities:

```
using (TheContext db = new TheContext())
{
    List<Computer> compQuery = (from compTrack in db.compTracking
                               where compTrack.AssetActionId == 1  // or compTrack.AssetAction.ID presumably
                               select compTrack.Computer).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't take into account computers that have never been checked out. I keep a complete list of all our computers in the model `Computer`

Answer (score 0):

After some research into linq, I came up with a fairly reliable solution based off of wahwahwah's answer. I simply replicated the SQL query in the original post and transcribed it to linq.

```
List<Computer> compQuery = (from comps in db.Computers
    join compTrack in db.ComputerTrackings on comps.Id equals compTrack.Computer.Id into compT
    from compTrack1 in compT.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where !(from o in db.ComputerTrackings
        select o.ComputerId).Contains(comps.Id) || compTrack1.AssetAction.Id == 1
    select comps).ToList();
```